# Display results from one table as link to show results to another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a game list that I want people to be able to go to the page games.php and select from  list of games and it would take them to the same page but as games.php?subgame=MetalGearRising.

Here's what I have so far.

```
      <?php
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT gamename FROM games ORDER BY gamename");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf("%s", $row["gamesname"] . "<br />");
}
      ?>
```

The subgame is subgame table and the name of the sub game is subgamename.

Right now it list them:
Final Fantasy
Metal Gear Solid
Yu-Gi-Oh

I can't figure out how to make the results clickable and when clicked take them to games.php?subgame=XXX and display all the sub games listed under that game for the subgame table. I do have auto increment, so I am not sure if I need to reference this in an innerjoin or what, I'm not too familiar with joins.

Any help would be appreciative.

EDIT: @Jesse

See thats where I get lost because I can't figure out how to link them together, because my sub games has the following rows:
subgameid
subgamename
subgamedescription

Say for example I clicked Metal Gear Solid and it took me to subgames.php?list=Metal Gear Solid, in which it should list results from subgame name specifically only for the 
Metal Gear Solid game in the games table. So say for example subgamename is Metal Gear Rising. Then it should only display that from the subgame table.

My code looks like this for subgames.php

```
$_GET['subgamename'];
if ($_REQUEST['do'] == $_GET['subgamename'];)
{
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT subgamename FROM items WHERE ID = "'.$id.'"');
}
```

But see the problem with that is I don't have the game name for it to print the results from? I mean surely there is an easier way to list it than to have to type in the
game name in two different tables?

@bobthyasian Actually this may be what I need to get it started here. Let me try this with my existing code.

It would actually be echo "

$row['gamesname']

"; but that works somewhat, but when I click a link I get Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /public_html/games.php on line 54. Im assuming because it doesn't reference back to the games table to know what subgame to list, which is the part I am comfused on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to use `$_GET[]` mixed with an `IF` `ELSE` like so:

```
<?php
$sub = $_GET['subgame'];
if($sub){
//Check if subgame selected
$result = mysql_query("SELECT $sub FROM games");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  //Display subgame info
 }
}
else{
//No subgame selected
//Display subgames
$result = mysql_query("SELECT gamename FROM games ORDER BY gamename");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   echo "<li><a href='game.php?subgame=".$row['gamesname']."</a></li><br />";
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: It would actually be echo "<li><a href='game.php?subgae=" . $row['gamesname'] . "'>$row['gamesname']</a></li><br />"; but that works somewhat, but when I click a link I get Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /public_html/games.php on line 54. Im assuming because it doesn't reference back to the games table to know what subgame to list, which is the part I am comfused on.

Answer (score 0):

So, your code would produce actual HTML and your printf would look more like this:

```
printf("<li><a href='games.php?subgame=%s'> %s </a></li>\n", $row["gamename"], $row["gamename"]);
```

-Jesse